# serialize text field to json

Tags: python, json, django, django-rest-framework

a third-party application I am using is storing json in a textfield.

I would like to serialize this data to json, and I only need to be able to read from this serializer, not write to it. I don't want to have to manipulate the data on the frontend, so I want it to come out at clean json from my api.

```
class SomeSerializer(serializers.ModelSerializer):

    details = serializers.CharField()

    class Meta:
        model = SomeModel
        fields = ( 'id', 'details')
```

right now this is returning:

```
[{"id":"someID",
  "details":"{\"address\": {\"city\": null}"}"}]
```

I can't figure out how to use json.loads in a serializer, which would seem the cleanest option.

Answer (score 2, accepted):

You can use [SerializerMethodField](https://www.django-rest-framework.org/api-guide/fields/#serializermethodfield).

```
import json
from rest_framework import serializers


class SomeSerializer(serializers.ModelSerializer):

    details = serializers.SerializerMethodField()

    class Meta:
        model = SomeModel
        fields = ('id', 'details')
    
    def get_details(self, obj):
        return json.loads(obj.details)
```

Note that SerializerMethodField is `read_only`, cannot for write.